# Asp.net dropdown always return one value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two rows in `Department` table.

```
ID  Name  
1   Commerce Department 
3   Human Resource Department
```

No matter what I select it always return **`ID=1`**.
Data is fetched and displayed from database correctly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        EmployeeLogic MLEdit = new EmployeeLogic();

        DepartmentLogic DL = new DepartmentLogic();
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataSource = DL.SelectAll();
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataTextField = "DepartmentName";
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataBind(); 
        Employee empp = MLEdit.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EID"]));
        MName.Text = empp.EmployeeName;
        DepartmentDropDownList.SelectedValue =empp.DepartmentID.ToString();
    }
}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["EID"] != null)
    {
        EmployeeLogic MLUpdate = new EmployeeLogic();
        Employee emp = MLUpdate.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EID"]));
        emp.EmployeeName = MName.Text;
        emp.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(DepartmentDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
        emp.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EID"]);
        MLUpdate.Update(emp);
    }
}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Department</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDropDownList" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DepartmentDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged1"> 
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: When you bind data to drop down list it always select first item in the table depend on order type...

Comment: what is the purpose of `DepartmentDropDownList.SelectedValue =empp.DepartmentID.ToString();`

Comment: After binding data, I am selecting dropdown item on Department ID. And its working, problem is when I change that option(value) , on submit it always returns 1 instead of 3.

Comment: @Nagaraj To display current department of Employee that is stored in db.
To set option (Department) of Employee

Comment: @TrushantPatel Can you show dropdown selected index changed event code behind ??

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        EmployeeLogic MLEdit = new EmployeeLogic();

        DepartmentLogic DL = new DepartmentLogic();
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataSource = DL.SelectAll();//This is the data source for DepartmentDropDownList
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataTextField = "DepartmentName";//This will appear at user side
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";//this the id of selected item 
        DepartmentDropDownList.DataBind();//Finally this will bind the dropdown with source. 
 DepartmentDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("0", "Select Item")); 
        Employee empp = MLEdit.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EID"]));
        MName.Text = empp.EmployeeName;
        DepartmentDropDownList.SelectedValue =empp.DepartmentID.ToString();
    }
}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["EID"] != null)
    {
        EmployeeLogic MLUpdate = new EmployeeLogic();
        Employee emp = MLUpdate.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EID"]));
        emp.EmployeeName = MName.Text;
        emp.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(DepartmentDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
        emp.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EID"]);
        MLUpdate.Update(emp);
    }
}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Department</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DepartmentDropDownList" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DepartmentDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged1"> 
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: What difference would it make?

Comment: here key is "0" and text is "Select One Item"

Comment: When you run asp page DDL bind the data from datatable and shows all data...Try it...then tell me..

Comment: `DepartmentDropDownList.DataSource = DL.SelectAll();`

Here SelectAll() returns datatable. I have already done that.

Comment: No Error, Same output.
Just your added option is new.
I don't understand, why are you adding an option (0,SelectedItem)

Comment: Can you show dropdown selected index changed event code behind

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
On index change event, I stored changed value in session object & on submit, stored in db from session. 
Thanks.